# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable while doing split

Tags: python, split

I have a test file which is below

```
Jan 23 2016 - bla bla mat_1 connected
Jan 23 2016 - bla bla mat_2 disconnected from company
```

My Code

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\test1.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        date, rest = line.split(' - ', 1)
        conn_disconn = rest.split(' ')
        print (conn_disconn)[3]
```

Expected Out

```
['connected']
['disconnected ']
```

Comment: The result is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array index is outside the print function.
This may solve:
`print (conn_disconn[3])`

Answer (score 1):

Look at your operation sequence here:

```
print(conn_disconn)[3]
```

You call `print` on `conn_discon`.  You take the return value of that call, and access the 3rd element.  This is not what you want.  `print` returns `None`, which pormpts your error message.

```
print (conn_disconn[3])
```

This will fetch element 3 of the list, and print that value.